# How to find the most effective use of a sum of money using inputted equipment costs?

Tags: java, loops, max

I've been working on a project for school for a couple hours now and still can't seem to get it right. I was instructed to take user inputs for 3 equipment prices, a total fund, and a remainder limit, and then figure out the amounts of the 3 equipment I can purchase in order to get the total cost as close to the maximum fund as possible while remaining inside the limit. The program must use a nested loop of some kind. This is what I have currently that is definitely not working:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GrandFund {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat fmt =  new DecimalFormat("#.##");

        int amt1 = 0, amt2 = 0, amt3 = 0;
        double price1, price2, price3, fund, limit, total1 = 0, total2 = 0, total3 = 0;

        System.out.println("Equipment #1 Price:");
        price1 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Equipment #2 Price:");
        price2 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Equipment #3 Price:");
        price3 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Total Fund Amount:");
        fund = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Remaining Fund Limit:");
        limit = scan.nextDouble();

        while((fund - (total1 + total2 + total3)) <= limit) {
            for(amt1 = 0; price1 * amt1 <= fund; amt1++) {
                total1 = price1 * amt1;
                for(amt2 = 0; price2 * amt2 <= fund - total1; amt2++) {
                    total2 = price2 * amt2;
                    for(amt3 = 0; price3 * amt3 <= fund - total1 - total2; amt3++) {
                        total3 = price3 * amt3;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        double remainder = fund - (total1 + total2 + total3);
        System.out.println(fmt.format(remainder) + ", " + fmt.format(amt1) + ", " + fmt.format(amt2) + ", " + fmt.format(amt3));
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing? I feel like I'm definitely on the right track, but I can't quite figure out where I went wrong. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "not working" isn't a working problem description. Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are required to make the solution efficient, the simplest method would be just an exhaustive search. That is trying all combinations and comparing to the 'best'.

The code might be a bit more elegant if you create a nested class to store a 'combination':

```
private class Combination {
    public Combination(int amount1, int amount2, int amount3) {
        ...
    }

    public int getCost() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then your trial code becomes much simpler:

```
Optional<Combination> best = Optional.empty();
for (int amount1 = ...) {
    for (int amount2 = ...) {
        for (int amount3 = ...) {
            Combination combo = new Combination(amount1, amount2, amount3);
            int cost = combo.getCost();
            if (cost < limit && (best.isEmpty() || cost > best.get().getCost()))
                best = Optional.of(combo);
        }
    }
}
```

This could be improved with an `Iterable<Combination>` to collapse the nested for loop but that's probably more complicated than you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need pick better result when do loop calculate. The Main logic is:

```
if (total1 + total2 + total3 > fund) {
    break;
}
//here is the code to pick the current better result
if (total1 + total2 + total3 <= fund
        && total1 + total2 + total3 >= fund - limit) {
    double currentCost = total1 + total2 + total3;
    if (currentCost > maxCost) {
        maxCost = currentCost;
        amountOfMaxCostOptional = Optional.of(new Amount(amt1, amt2, amt3));
    }
}
```

Below is the whole code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GrandFund {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

        int amt1 = 0, amt2 = 0, amt3 = 0;
        double price1, price2, price3, fund, limit, total1 = 0, total2 = 0, total3 = 0;

        System.out.println("Equipment #1 Price:");
        price1 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Equipment #2 Price:");
        price2 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Equipment #3 Price:");
        price3 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Total Fund Amount:");
        fund = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Remaining Fund Limit:");
        limit = scan.nextDouble();

        double maxCost = 0d;
        Optional<Amount> amountOfMaxCostOptional = Optional.empty();
        for (amt1 = 0; price1 * amt1 <= fund; amt1++) {
            total1 = price1 * amt1;

            for (amt2 = 0; price2 * amt2 <= fund - total1; amt2++) {
                total2 = price2 * amt2;

                for (amt3 = 0; price3 * amt3 <= fund - total1 - total2; amt3++) {
                    total3 = price3 * amt3;

                    if (total1 + total2 + total3 > fund) {
                        break;
                    }
                    //here is the code to pick the current better result
                    if (total1 + total2 + total3 <= fund
                            && total1 + total2 + total3 >= fund - limit) {
                        double currentCost = total1 + total2 + total3;
                        if (currentCost > maxCost) {
                            maxCost = currentCost;
                            amountOfMaxCostOptional = Optional.of(new Amount(amt1, amt2, amt3));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        amountOfMaxCostOptional.ifPresent(amountOfMaxCost -> {
            double remainder =
                    fund - (amountOfMaxCost.getAmt1() * price1 + amountOfMaxCost.getAmt2() * price2
                            + amountOfMaxCost.getAmt3() * price3);
            System.out.println(
                    fmt.format(remainder) + ", " + fmt.format(amountOfMaxCost.getAmt1()) + ", "
                            + fmt.format(amountOfMaxCost.getAmt2()) + ", " + fmt
                            .format(amountOfMaxCost.getAmt3()));
        });
        scan.close();
    }

    private static class Amount {
        private double amt1;
        private double amt2;
        private double amt3;

        public Amount(double amt1, double amt2, double amt3) {
            this.amt1 = amt1;
            this.amt2 = amt2;
            this.amt3 = amt3;
        }

        public double getAmt1() {
            return amt1;
        }

        public double getAmt2() {
            return amt2;
        }

        public double getAmt3() {
            return amt3;
        }
    }
}
```